# Check Integer Validation on texbox using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried with below Keycode but its not working.

**HTML:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDays" runat="server" TabIndex="1" autocomplete="off" CssClass="form-control"
                                    placeholder=" " onkeypress="return integerValidation(this)" onblur="ShowMaterial('', 'BindGridview')" onfocus="return validateOnFoucs(this)"
                                    Text="60" MaxLength="3"></asp:TextBox>
```

**Js:**

```
 function integerValidation(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode > 100 && (charCode < 58 || charCode > 90)) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you just want to make sure what's in the input is an integer? Why don't you use `parseInt()` instead of checking for char codes? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: Sure .I'll check with that solution ! @MelanciaUK

Comment: Also, use `onkeyup` instead. http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/7z9Lu5qu/

Comment: if you want to Check Integer Validation on texbox using Javascript then why dont you use regular expressions? use them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isNaN` with `Number` or `parseInt`

`isNaN` Will return true if the value isn't a number and false if it is(Is Not A Number).

Some this like this:

```
function integerValidation(input)
{
   return !isNaN(Number(input.value));
}
```

Or:

```
function integerValidation(input)
{
   return !parseInt(input.value);
}
```

Comment: I'd use only `Number`, because, in this case for example `parseInt("139312a")` would return `139312`, but `Number("139312a")` returns `NaN`. Thus `Number` returns `NaN` when the input is not a number, and `parseInt`, as the name says, "parses" to get the number in the input.

Comment: @MelanciaUK - your'e right..I just copy-pasted the Number answer(which I prefer).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not correct.

```
return integerValidation(this)
```

Use this instead.

```
return integerValidation(event)
```

and your logic seems wrong

```
if (charCode > 100 && (charCode < 58 || charCode > 90))
```